# Merge [vbs] into [vbscript]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we merge [vbs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vbs) into [vbscript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) and synonymize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could distinguish it more from [vba](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba). Which I'd like. I agree with the merge+synonymize suggestion.